# C#: Regex with digits and slash in the middle

Tags: c#, regex

So i have string with digits and words for example:

```
1283677/10, this is my string, bla bla
```

And i want to take only the serial number: `1283677/10`

This is what i have try:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(text, @"\d{8}(/\d{1,2})?");
```

Currently return empty.

Comment: Is the serial number always retrievable by taking whatever is before the **first** comma? Because that's a lot easier than using a regex...

Answer (score 4):

You have 7 digits in the part before slash. So the fix is fair simple:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(text, @"\d{7}(/\d{1,2})?");
```

Comment: As question title is _"Regex with digits **and slash**"_ then I assume the slash & following digits are required - so maybe the final question mark should be removed - otherwise "1234567" could be matched.

Comment: Agree, title is somewhat confusing, but I believe second part was marked as optional intentionally.